# Multiple ListBox/Collection Items Selected for MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection, multipleselection

I have a listbox that is bound to an ObservableCollection of Names. Some of the items in the list will have a checkbox that is toggled on/off, indicating the item has been selected.

How do I create an ObservableCollection from the selected items of the first listbox following the Master-Details concept?

(I plan to use my MasterViewModel as the DataContext for my DetailsView which displays the selected items Collection.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, I've come across this before as well. ListBoxes and the like have a dependency property called 'SelectedItem', but the 'SelectedItems' (with an 's') property is not implemented as one.

The cleanest solution I've found is just to subclass the listbox, and create my own dependency property called 'SelectedItems'. No fun, but it's I think the best solution.

**UPDATE**

First our ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Set up our collection to be read from the View
    public ObservableCollection<String> Collection { get; private set; }

    // This collection will maintain the selected items
    public ObservableCollection<String> SelectedItems { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        // Instantiate
        this.Collection = new ObservableCollection<String>();
        this.SelectedItems = new ObservableCollection<String>();

        // Now let's monitor when this.SelectdItems changes
        this.SelectedItems.CollectionChanged += SelectedItems_CollectionChanged;

        // Fill our collection with some strings (1 to 10).
        // (1) Generate the numbers 1 - 10
        // (2) Convert each number to a string
        // (3) Cast into a list so we can use foreach 
        // (4) Add each item to the collection.
        Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
            .Select(number => number.ToString())   
            .ToList()                              
            .ForEach(this.Collection.Add);

        // Remember! Never reset the ObservableCollection.
        // That is, never say this.Collection = new... (or you'll break the binding).
        // instead use this.Collection.Clear(), and then add the items you want to add
    }

    void SelectedItems_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            foreach (String str in this.SelectedItems)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("New item added {0}", str);

        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Then our extended ListBoxEx:

```
class ListBoxEx : ListBox
{
    // Use the 'new' keyword so that we 'hide' the base property.
    // This means that binding will go to this version of SelectedItems
    // rather than whatever the base class uses. To reach the base 'SelectedItems' property
    // We just need to use base.SelectedItems instead of this.SelectedItems
    // Note that we register as an observable collection.
    new DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(ObservableCollection<String>), typeof(ListBoxEx));

    // Accessor. Again, note the 'new'.
    new public ObservableCollection<String> SelectedItems
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<String>) GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Guard against ViewModel being null
        if (this.SelectedItems != null)
        {
            // Clear the list
            this.SelectedItems.Clear();

            // (1) On selection changed. Get the new base.SelectedItems
            // (2) Cast each item to a String ("Make a string collection")
            // (3) Cast to list, and use foreach to add each item to 
            // this.SelectedItems (note this is different from the original base.SelectedItems)
            base.SelectedItems.Cast<String>()
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(this.SelectedItems.Add);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally our View:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <lol:ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <lol:ListBoxEx ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems}"
                   SelectionMode="Multiple"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of adding an "isSelected" bool to the viewmodel, and then creating an ObservableCollection of those on a new "details" viewmodel where that is true. I'm not sure how this would work out though.

As for your "multiple selections in the listbox" comment--I have a feeling this can be tackled by setting SelectionMode="Multiple" or SelectionMode="Extended"

Comment: Well adding an isSelected bool to the objects themselves would work. But 'isSelected' is a view property, not a model/viewModel property - so while it works, it's technically incorrect. Also, in your original post, it sounds like you want to populate a collection made up of those items that are selected. The problem is that to get those items down to the vm, you have to have a dependency property, but no such thing exists - you would have to make one yourself unfortunately.

Comment: oh not to the objects, but the _viewmodel_ objects. Somebody pointed out to me in another question that Josh Smith does this in his blogs.

Comment: What about raising the PropertyChanged event for the item that is selected, and adding it ObservableCollection of Selections?

Comment: Well that does make sense then. Just have an observable collection specifically for the view. Yeah that sounds good.

Comment: You know, after looking at different options again I think you're approach is the most accommodating for my current viewmodel design. Do you have any links I could use as reference? Thank you!

Comment: Example added. Let me know if you have any more questions.